# Call custom controller in custom module for Magento

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller

I have created a custom module in magento 1.9.2 named " question & answer "

I have the phtml file placed in directory `magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/template/question.phtml`

[image]

now, the form action should validate the form and I have the controller placed in `magento/app/code/local/Mynamespace/Questions/controllers`
I have the below index controller

[image]

and I want to call the questionAction .Bit confused as I am a neophyte with this technology. Any help to this will be appreciated much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you can do is in your phtml file, write this in your form action :

```
<form action = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('yourRouterName/index/question'); ?>">
```

And this router name you would have written in your config.xml, while defining the package(or module).